# How to Change Existing Repository Url in Podfile , Update all pods into New Repository

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile, podfile-lock

While a updating pod file it's asking big-bucket password using existing repository, but i don't have password (vendor big-bucket repository) , i would like change repository url. can you please share how i can change url.

```
 platform :ios, '10.0'
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
target 'Gaadi Bazaar' do

source 'vendor repository url.git' 
#source 'own repository url.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  # Pods for GaadiBazaar
      pod 'IXKit', '~> 0.1.3'
      pod 'IXNetwork', '~> 0.1.2'
      pod 'TTRangeSlider'
      pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
      pod 'SideMenu', '~> 4.0.0'
      pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
      pod 'LocaleManager'
      pod 'Fabric'
      pod 'Crashlytics'
      pod 'YouTubePlayer'

end
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end

#post_install do |installer|
#    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
#        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
#        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
#    end
#end
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.new_shell_script_build_phase.shell_script = "mkdir -p $PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/#{target.name}"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4'
            config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If you found any answer useful then you can click on accepted. It just take 5 seconds but a nice way to appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```rb
pod 'SomePod', :git => 'https://github.com/someUser/SomePod'
```

Answer (score 1):

To change repository url you can follow as below
To use the **master branch** of the repository:

```
pod 'AKPickerView-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/mrugeshtank/AKPickerView-Swift.git'
```

To use a different **branch** of the repository:

```
pod 'AKPickerView-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/mrugeshtank/AKPickerView-Swift.git', :branch => 'someBranchName'
```

To use a **tag** of the repository:

```
pod 'AKPickerView-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/mrugeshtank/AKPickerView-Swift.git', :tag => '2.0.0'
```

Or a scpecific **commit**:

```
pod 'AKPickerView-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/mrugeshtank/AKPickerView-Swift.git', :commit => '5edfe3a'
```

You can find more documentation about podfile [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)